How do I configure ESLint in VS Code for JS module script
I am using VS Code to work on a web page (using Leaflet). In my index.html I run the JS with:
<script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>

I am using an ESLint plugin with VS Code and I want it to use strict JS rules for the linting, but though I have a "use strict"; at the top of main.js, it is only showing problems for non-strict issues.
I have an eslint.config.js file in the root of my project which looks like this:
import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";

export default [
  {languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser }},
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
];

What do I need to change to get ESLint to get it to respond to the "use strict"; command and what to do to make it the default so it's not needed?
Thanks

use strict is not needed for ecmascript modules. It's implied.

ESLint is not applying strict rules when processing my script. It's not reporting problems I know are present, such as using a variable without declaring it first.

That's possible, but I don't think use strict controls what ESLint warn or doesn't warn you on!

You can use these properties in parserOptions to enable strict mode: "sourceType": "module" & in the ecmaFeatures object "impliedStrict": true
your eslint config should look like this
import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";

export default [
  {languageOptions: { 
    globals: globals.browser,
    parserOptions: {
       sourceType: "module",
       ecmaFeatures: {impliedStrict: true}
    }
}},
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
];

For further information here is the documentation for use strict in eslint: docs

This solves most of my problems, however my code isn't actually using "module" script imports in the HTML, and in my 2ndary scripts I'm defining global constants which I reference in my main.js. I thought I'd be able to use /* exported {symbol name} */ but that is being ignored.
